# Include $_POST, $_GET, $_SERVER values in PHP Error Log

Tags: php

I have code like this

```
try {
    header("Location: http://www.google.com\n-abc");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
    error_log(print_r($_GET, true));
    error_log(print_r($_SERVER, true));
}
```

Without the try {} catch {} block, I can see the POST, GET and SERVER variables in my error_log, but with the try {} catch {} block, I only see the default PHP error.

1. Is there a way to show the POST, GET, and SERVER variables in a try {} catch {} block?
2. Is there a way to have PHP include POST, GET, and SERVER variables for ALL errors that get logged to file and not just wherever I have added error_log(print_r($_POST, true)); ....?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. What are you trying to do?

Comment: because no exception has been thrown?

Comment: I think your question needs some more information. It's hard to follow exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But default PHP functions like `header` will not throw exceptions.

If you want them to throw exceptions you will need to set the error handler to use [ErrorException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php):

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to have set_error_handler("exception_error_handler") be applied to ALL pages and not just the ones where I have called set_error_handler(). I want this error handler to work for all scripts without my having to manually add it in each script. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any PHP files that are included in each page (for example a config file or a functions file)? If so add the error handler in there.

Answer (score 2):

try/catch is for when you want to throw an exception to prevent php fatal errors from killing the page or to make debugging easier, generally speaking. This is how you would use a try/catch:

```
try {
    if($a === true)
    {
        header("Location: http://www.google.com\n-abc");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('$a was not true');
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
    error_log(print_r($_GET, true));
    error_log(print_r($_SERVER, true));
    echo $e->getMessage(); // $a was not true
}
```

The reason you don't see your error logs in the catch block in your example is because you never threw an exception so PHP will never look inside that catch block to log your variables.

If you simply want to get your example to work you'd just throw an exception to get PHP in that catch block:

```
try 
{
    throw new Exception('redirecting...');
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    error_log(print_r($_POST, true));
    error_log(print_r($_GET, true));
    error_log(print_r($_SERVER, true));
    header("Location: http://www.google.com\n-abc");

}
```

That's just silly though :)

Comment: **Moderator Note:** _Please keep comments constructive and on topic. As comments on this answer degenerated into noise, I have removed them._

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few questions/issues here.

First, a try/catch block is used for Exceptions. The catch {} code is only executed if a Exception of the type specified is thrown.

Second, the header() function does not throw exceptions. Instead it just generates a PHP error directly.

Thirdly, to log those variables for all errors take a look at [set_error_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), which should also take care of the above, second issue.

Answer (score 0):

try/catch would only work if you're using an object that actually throws exception. header() is NOT an object and will NEVER throw an exception. Like I said in my answer to [your previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366810/user366810) of this question, you need to set up a custom error handler.

Comment: Functions can throw exceptions too.

Comment: To clarify - PHP Docs say: `Internal PHP functions mainly use Error reporting, only modern Object oriented extensions use exceptions. However, errors can be simply translated to exceptions with ErrorException.`

Comment: Ya bro, you missed the part where the docs were referring to **internal PHP functions**.

Answer (score 0):

That's how try/catch is supposed to work: the catch block executes when an exception is thrown in the try block (and only in that case).

The header() function may generate a *warning* if headers are already sent, but it will never throw an exception.

Answering your questions:

1. Your catch block is just fine but you need code that can actually throw exceptions (typically object-oriented code, but not necessarily). However, you can configure PHP to convert regular errors into exceptions if you use [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/set_error_handler) to create a custom error handler and use `throw` inside of it.
2. Same as above: [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and [set_exception_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to have some extra information output to your log when an error is thrown. You should check out custom error handling in PHP. You can define specific ways to handle errors in your scripts and add functionality that is not there by default.[PHP Set error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)